# Is a bootable OSX USB stick live: can try, to test an app?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, liveusb

I want to test my OSX app on an older version of OSX (10.8).  Will a 'bootable install USB stick' (official from Apple) be live?  That is, like a Ubuntu stick that offers the choice of 'install' or 'try' (with a RAMdisk)?  Alternatively, can I install 10.8 in VirtualBox on 10.9?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not be a live environment.  An OS X Install USB stick is only usable for installing the OS.

You can, however, install the operating system to a USB stick.  Just insert another stick, format it with Disk Utility, and then select it as the install destination.  That stick would then be the live install you're looking for.